# soap client must implement the callback handler if server use the wss4j?

Tags: security, soap, wss4j

I plan to implement a open soap server using wss4j techonogy, and the wsdl had standard one, so, how to make client using my server if it had not implement the wss4j callbackhandler?

Comment: or, it there a way to make client connect to server using none-security communication?

Comment: Please correct all mistakes in your text, check if you missed something there, stop commenting on your own question and instead edit your question. Thank you!